# Python- dictionary with list of list elements

Tags: python

Edit: Sorry - I am very inexperienced at basically all of this.  I will try again.

It appears that my dictionaries are messed up somehow because when I call the function, most of the results are `nan`

Please let me know if you need anything in addition to the below, I barely know how to write code and I certainly don't know how to fix other peoples code so just let me know what other info you may need.

```
    N_SAMPLES = 10000

IEA_LV = fin_data['Yield_IEA'][0]
IEA_STD = fin_data['Yield_IEA'].std()

IBL_LV = fin_data['Cost_IBL'][0]
IBL_STD = fin_data['Cost_IBL'].std()

# Proxy for Default Rate- See Notes
fin_data['NPL'] = fin_data['NPL_to_Loan']*fin_data['Total_Loans']
NPL_LV = fin_data['NPL'][0]


# default rate info (based on past due loans)
default_mean = fin_data['Default_Rate'].mean()
default_std = fin_data['Default_Rate'].std()
LGD = fin_data['LGD'][0]
prior_LGD = fin_data['LGD'][1]

fin_data['non_int_exp_toAssets'] = fin_data['Non_Int_Exp']/fin_data['Total_Loans']

# non-interest expense info
nonint_exp_LV = fin_data['non_int_exp_toAssets'][0]
nonint_exp_STD = fin_data['non_int_exp_toAssets'].std()

#deposit info
dep_LV = fin_data['Deposits'][0]
dep_STD = fin_data['Deposits'].std()
dep_min = fin_data['Deposits'].min()


# Loan growth information

fin_data['loan_g'] = fin_data['Total_Loans']/fin_data['Total_Loans'].shift(-1) - 1
loan_g_min = fin_data['loan_g'].min()
loan_g_avg = fin_data['loan_g'].mean()
loan_g_std = fin_data['loan_g'].std()


w_minus_r = fin_data['Net_Chg_Off'].mean() 

def_credit_flow = default_mean*fin_data['Total_Loans'][0]

# Projected NPLs
next_NPL = NPL_LV + def_credit_flow + NPL_LV * (1 - w_minus_r)

#Net adjustment for impaired loans needs LGD updated
adj_imp_loans = def_credit_flow * LGD + NPL_LV * (1-w_minus_r) * (LGD - prior_LGD)

# Reserve for Loan Loss

ALLL = fin_data['ALLL'][0] * fin_data['Total_Loans'][0] + adj_imp_loans - NPL_LV * w_minus_r


# variable: [most recent value or average, standard deviation]

var_stats_dict = {'IEA': [IEA_LV, IEA_STD], 'IBL': [IBL_LV, IBL_STD], 'Default Rate': [default_mean, default_std],
                 'Non Int Exp': [nonint_exp_LV, nonint_exp_STD],
                 'GPL': [loan_g_avg, loan_g_std], 'Deposits': [dep_LV, dep_STD]}


# var: [[min, max for severe], [min, max for moderate], [min, max for low]]
# severe = 0, moderate = 1, low = 2


severity_dict = {'IEA': [[IEA_LV - 3 * IEA_STD, IEA_LV + 1 * IEA_STD],
                         [IEA_LV - 2 * IEA_STD, IEA_LV + 2 * IEA_STD],
                         [IEA_LV - 1 * IEA_STD, IEA_LV + 3 * IEA_STD]], 
                'IBL': [[IBL_LV - 1 * IBL_STD, IBL_LV + 3 * IBL_STD],
                        [IBL_LV - 2 * IBL_STD, IBL_LV + 2 * IBL_STD],
                        [IBL_LV - 3 * IBL_STD, IBL_LV + 1 * IBL_STD]],
                'Default Rate': [[default_mean - 1 * default_std,
                                  default_mean + 3 * default_std],
                                 [default_mean - 2 * default_std,
                                  default_mean + 2 * default_std],
                                 [default_mean - 3 * default_std,
                                  default_mean + 1 * default_std]],
                'Non Int Exp': [nonint_exp_LV - 1 * nonint_exp_STD,
                                nonint_exp_LV + 1 * nonint_exp_STD],
                'GPL': [[loan_g_min, loan_g_avg],
                        [loan_g_avg - 1 * loan_g_std, loan_g_avg + 1 * loan_g_std],
                        [loan_g_avg, loan_g_avg + 2 * loan_g_std]],
                'Deposits': [[dep_min, dep_LV],
                             [dep_LV - 1 * dep_STD, dep_LV + 1 * dep_STD],
                             [dep_LV, dep_LV + 2 * dep_STD]]}


#vars = IEA, IBL, Default Rate, Non Int Exp, GPL, Deposits
def mc_generator(var, severity):
    low_cap = severity_dict[var][severity][0]
    up_cap = severity_dict[var][severity][1]
    mu = var_stats_dict[var][0]
    sigma = var_stats_dict[var][1]


    container = []

    for i in range(0, N_SAMPLES):
        x = np.random.normal(loc = mu, scale = sigma)
        result = stats.beta.pdf(x, low_cap, up_cap)
        container.append(result)

    avg_val = sum(container)/N_SAMPLES
    return round(avg_val, 10)




print(mc_generator('Non Int Exp', 0))
```

Comment: _Function is returning nan_ Show us the calling code.  All I see here is a function definition that is never actually called.

Comment: Could you add an [mcve] showing a complete minimal working version of your code? For example, are you simply calling `mc_generator()`? Answering your question is difficult without knowing the full context of the problem.

Comment: As it stands, the indentation of the first line needs to be corrected, your dictionaries are populated with variables that are not defined in your code, and we have no idea what you are doing to call your function. Without those, it's not really practical for anyone to try to answer.